# gif анимация перестала двигатся

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сохранить gif

```
$url = "gif/yH.gif";

$type_img = explode (".", $url);

    switch(strtolower($type_img[count($type_img)-1])) {
        case "gif": $img1 = imagecreatefromgif($url); break;
    }


    imagegif ($img1, "gif/img.gif");
```

Исходный файл весит меньше оригинала и не двигается, как сохранить анимацию?

Comment: __Никак__ конечно же.

Comment: а чего вы с ней хотите сделать то? размеры изменить,  или что?